# Raise event from another Application

Tags: c#, events

**I have 3 projects:**

1. Consumer (Exe): Shows the list of items.
2. Connection (Dll): Save/Get items from database.
3. Producer (Exe): Creates/Updates items.

**So this is what I'm trying to do:**

Everytime the producer updates an item using a Connection method, a DataGridView inside the Consumer should be updated.

So, I started using events... Inside the Connection Project.

**This is my Update methods (I call this after the DataBase update):**

```
public delegate void UpdatedEventHandler(object source, UpdateArgs e);

public class UpdateArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly DateTime _date;

    public UpdateArgs(DateTime now)
    {
        _date = now;
    }
}

public static class UpdateUtil
{
    public static event UpdatedEventHandler OnUpdate;

    public static void Raise(object info)
    {
        if (OnUpdate!= null)
        {
            OnUpdate(info, new UpdateArgs(DateTime.Now));
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my action map:**

1. Open the Consumer, register the event handler: 
                `UpdateUtil.OnUpdateNfe += Object_OnUpdate;`
2. Open the Producer, add a new item.
3. In the Producer, call `UpdateUtil.Raise(something);`, to update an item.
4. Here is the problem: The Consumer should have now the updated item in the `DataGridView`

**Problem:**

The `OnUpdate` variable is always null. Even if I registered in the Consumer app.

**Question:**

How to raise an event from another executable?

Comment: You're looking for "Inter process communication (IPC)" before that you need to understand about process memory and the scope of static events etc

Comment: Owhhh, It's a little bit more complicated than I expected, since they use the same Connection project. I'll probably going to use a `Socket`.

Comment: @NickeManarin Sockets will work.  If your executables are running on the same machine you might find it a little easier to use an AutoResetEvent.  Named events can be shared between processes.

Comment: @RogerN The producer can run standalone in another PC, like 1 server and 100's of clients (The database is the link between both). `Socket` it is.

Comment: @NickeManarin Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) might be another approach, instead of writing your own comms protocol.

Comment: Done, using `Sockets`. I can post the code if someone wants it.